# Reset form if php upload is done

Tags: php, html

may i know how to reset my form or refreshing my page after done uploading my file without any issue?  What i need to mention is the html file will be store on root directory and the php file store in root/php/upload_action.php

here my HTML code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="./php/upload_action.php" method="POST">
     Model to upload: <input type="file" name="userfile" required="required"
     <input type="reset" value="reset">><input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Here will be my PHP code:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

      echo '<script language="javascript">';
      echo 'alert("Done!")';
      echo '</script>';

} else {
     echo '<script language="javascript">';
      echo 'alert("Failed! Try again later...")';
      echo '</script>';
}
```

Comment: does this `echo 'alert("Done!")';` work?

Comment: You can use a [header location](https://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) redirect.

Comment: @hungrykoala Yes, its work fine. After i click on the OK button it just stay at the upload_action.php with empty page.

Comment: you can add `echo 'window.location.reload()';`

Comment: @hungrykoala dosent seems working, they just print out window.location.reload()

Comment: @JefferyLR try `echo 'location.reload()';`

Comment: @hungrykoala with the colon wont work, it will just print out what is in that colon.

Comment: `echo '<script>';
 echo 'location.reload()';
 echo '</script>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ob_start();
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

      echo '<script language="javascript">';
      echo 'alert("Done!")';
      echo '</script>';
      header( "refresh:0; url=pagename.php" );

}
```

Comment: Hi, i did try this before but showing me an error message.

Comment: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /root/php/upload_action.php:10) in /root/php/upload_action.php on line 16

Comment: add ob_start(); at the top of this php file and check

Comment: Its working! But my alert box is gone after that, anyway to redirect only after i clink OK button on the alert page?

Comment: try putting the header line before the echo script

Comment: i dont have any other solution, sorry

Comment: No problem. Do you mind adding ob_start(); to your solution and leave some comment?

Comment: using refresh:0 and url instead of Location solved my issue. With really appreciate your help.